# Convert ArrayList to List<GenericModel> gives ClassCastException

Tags: java, exception, casting, classcastexception

I am converting stored procedure to complete JPA query. One of the SP query is as below which i am converting to entity class. I am converting this to a bean defined as Generic model which results in classcastexception.

SP query whose result set rs4 in java class is as follows:

```
 rs4 Query: select command_value as descr from SCAN_COMMAND_NAME 
            where command_name = 'AAA' ORDER BY SEQ;
```

Here the result set rs4 is converted to GenericModel:

```
ResultSet rs4 = (ResultSet) cs.getObject(cnt++);
List commandRotateLi = new BeanProcessor().toBeanList(rs4,GenericModel.class);
session.setAttribute("coRotate", commandRotateLi);
///...
..///
ArrayList coRotate = (ArrayList) session.getAttribute("coRotate");
for(int x = 0; x < coRotate.size(); x++){
    gm = (GenericModel) coRotate.get(x);
    ///
}
```

This above code works fine. Below is JPA converted code.

```
List<ScanCommandName> scanCommandList = new ArrayList<ScanCommandName>();
query = em.createNamedQuery("ScanCommandName.findByCommandName", ScanCommandName.class);
query.setParameter("commandName", Constants.IMAGE_MAGICK_ROTATE);
scanCommandList = query.getResultList();
```

scanCommandList.toString() gives me 5 ScanCommandName objects. I have to convert this List to List and loop through as above one but struck at class cast exception in the for loop.

```
ArrayList list =  new ArrayList();
List<GenericModel> coRotate = null;
for(int y=0; y<scanCommandList.size(); y++){
    ScanCommandName s = scanCommandList.get(y);
    list.add(s.getCommandValue());            
}
coRotate = (List<GenericModel>) (List) list;
```

I am now looping through the List coRotate but getting classcast at the 1st line in for loop.

```
for(int x = 0; x < coRotate.size(); x++){
    gm = (GenericModel) coRotate.get(x);
    ///
}
```

java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to com.GenericModel

Any suggestions highly appreciated. thank you.

Comment: Your problems started when you created a raw `ArrayList`.  What type does `s.getCommandValue()` return?  It would appear to be a `String`.  And as the exception says, you can't cast a `String` to a `GenericModel`

Answer (score 0):

This is essentially what you are doing:

```
    ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
    List<SomeClass> slist;
    list.add("String"); // <-- I'm guessing here based on exception
    slist = (List<SomeClass>) list;

    for (SomeClass s : slist) { // class cast exception
        System.out.println(s);
    }


class SomeClass {

}
```

Had you done this:

```
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

You could not have done this

```
    slist = (List<SomeClass>) list;
```

And the error would have been caught at compile time.

Without knowing the details of your class structure, I suspect that to do what you want, `coRotate` needs to hold instances of `GenericModel` and
your `ArrayList` needs to be declared as `ArrayList<GenericModel> = new ArrayList<>()`